# Не переведена ссылка на странице инструментов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

На странице [инструментов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools) не переведён текст "site analytics", хотя на самой странице [аналитики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) заголовок на русском. Разные ресурсы используются для текста?

Comment: Действитель, похоже, что строки нет. Написал ребятам, чтобы добавили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил 18 января — исправлено.

---

Вероятно, это [Transfex:7160](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/60364569?key=a2729898b174059f3e5a482914debe4d)

> site analytics
>   статистика сайта

Других подобных строк в базе нет. Вероятно, строку захардкодили.